# Highlighting overflow with CSS / Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm wondering how to bring attention to a section that has more information than is showed on the screen. Essentially, the way it currently looks, it might only appear that there is one piece of data in the table, but in reality there is a scroll window.  I'd like to bring attention to the fact that there is more data, you just need to scroll.  I added the border and that at least started to help.

http://jsfiddle.net/xG3uc/

How would you highlight that there is more data but you just need to scroll to see it?

```
.but_there_is_more {
    max-height: 50px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    border: 1px dotted #ccc;
}
```

Maybe if the div expands over the max-height, have some javascript to show a link to "expand" the rest?

Comment: Why isn't the scrollbar enough as an indicator of such behavior?

Comment: @elclanrs scrollbars are not shown by default in all browsers/OSes. A common pattern is to add a gradient overlay at the edge so that the content fades out.

Comment: @steveax: Oh I see, you mean a shadow like Google does in some of their apps?

Comment: @elclanrs yes. Amazon does this too on some screens (reviews IIRC)

Comment: Check this talk, the first example discusses how to create a similar effect with just CSS http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=3ikye7Qc7Ak#t=237s

Comment: The scrollbar is generally enough, but for the quick glance, some of the users may not realize there is more information.  I just want to make sure it pops out.

Answer (score 1):

Want to try qTip2? Check DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/yeyene/xG3uc/10/

## JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.a')
        .qtip({
        content: {
            text: 'Scroll for more data!'
        },
        position: {
            my: 'bottom right',
            at: 'bottom right'
        },
        show: {
            event: 'mouseover',
            ready: true // show the tooltip when ready                        
        },
        hide: {
            event: 'click unfocus' // click anywhere to hide
        },          
        style: {
            classes: 'ui-tooltip-red'
        }
    });
});
```

Source and Doc of qTip2 http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/demos/

Comment: Definitely one possible solution...  I'll have to read up on the documentation to see how well it will work for my use case.

Comment: Yes, check the Show and Hide event and effects, you can play around on this Show and Hide events, http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/docs/